# Varnish, Nginx, SSL - IP detection issue

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, ip, varnish

Hi I have a very strange issue and the hosting company is telling me its not possible I am hoping you guys can help.

I have a nginx / varnish which acts as a load balancer and cache sitting in front of my webservers. My web servers are standard apache web servers.

I am having problems with detecting the genuine IP address of users connecting to the system. The $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] shows the IP address of the load balancer/cache and not of the user visiting the site.

We have written a hack so that with HTTP traffic we send through an X-Forwarded-For header with the correct IP address, but I have been told this is not possible with SSL.

Unfortunately due to strict security requirements we are not able to offload SSL onto the load balancer/cache it has to go to apache.

Has anyone got any ideas on how we could detect the IP address, when using SSL?

thanks for the help, Si

--- VCL Config ---

```
import std;

C{
        #include <stdlib.h>
}C



sub vcl_recv {    
/* Add X-Forwarded-For header */
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
    }



    /* Fix compression */
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(ico|png|jpe?g|gif|xpm|swf|flv|pdf|mp3|ogg|zip|gz|tgz|bz2|xz|7z)$") {
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    /* Handle SSL offloading */
    if (client.ip == "127.0.0.1") {
        std.log("SSL offloading detected " + client.ip + " " + req.http.X-Real-IP);
        set client.identity = req.http.X-Real-IP;
    } else {
        set client.identity = client.ip;
    }

    if (req.http.Cookie) {
       set client.identity = req.http.Cookie;
    }


    set req.http.X-Varnish-XID = req.xid;
    set req.backend = lb231;

    if (req.backend.healthy) {
        set req.grace = 30s;
    } else {
        set req.grace = 1h;
    }

        call normalise_user_agent;

    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        return(lookup);
    }

    if (req.request != "GET" &&
       req.request != "HEAD" &&
       req.request != "PUT" &&
       req.request != "POST" &&
       req.request != "TRACE" &&
       req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
       req.request != "DELETE") {
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.http.Cookie) {
                set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
                set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
                set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(PHPSESSID)=", "; \1="); # Cookies to keep here
                set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
                set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

                if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
                        remove req.http.Cookie;
                }
    }

    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
         return (pass);
    }


    if (req.url ~ "/nocache") {
        set req.http.X-No-Cache = "true";
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.request == "BAN") {
        if (client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 401 "Forbidden";
        }
        ban("req.http.Host == " + req.http.X-VCL-Ban-Host + " && req.url ~ " + req.http.X-VCL-Ban-URL);
        error 200 "Ban OK " + req.url + " " + req.http.Host;
    }

    if (req.request == "REFRESH") {
        set req.request = "GET";
        set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }

    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (lookup);
}


    if (beresp.status >= 400) {
        /* Cache error pages for a short amount of time */
        set beresp.ttl = 5s;
        set beresp.grace = 5s;
        set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=5, must-revalidate";
        unset beresp.http.Cookie;
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    }

    if (beresp.status == 503) {
        /* Do not cache 503s at all */
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
        set beresp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    }

     if (beresp.http.X-Varnish-TTL) {
        C{
            char *ttl;
            ttl = VRT_GetHdr(sp, HDR_BERESP, "\016X-Varnish-TTL:");
            VRT_l_beresp_ttl(sp, atoi(ttl));
        }C
        #unset beresp.http.X-Varnish-TTL;
    } else {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    }

    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "No, not cacheable.";
    } elsif (req.http.Cookie ~ "(UserID|_session)") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "No, got session.";
        return(hit_for_pass);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "No, Cache-Control=private";
        return(hit_for_pass);
    } else {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "Yes.";
        set beresp.grace = 1h;
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.reset-client-side-age) {
       unset resp.http.reset-client-side-age;
       set resp.http.Age = "0";
    }

    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "Hit";
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "Miss";
    }

    if (resp.http.Server == "Varnish") {
        set resp.http.Server = "OnCommerce Framework Ltd";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.X-Scrubbed-For;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
}

sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}

sub vcl_error {

}

sub normalise_user_agent
{
                if(req.http.user-agent ~ "Mobile"){
                                set req.http.X-UA = "mobile";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "Android")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "android";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "Opera Mini/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "mobile";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "Opera Mobi/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "mobile";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "iP(ad|od|hone)/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "iOS";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "MSIE/")
                {
                                if(req.http.user-agent ~ "MSIE\s[1-7]/")
                                {
                                                set req.http.X-UA = "desktop-old";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                                set req.http.X-UA = "desktop";
                                }
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "Chrome/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "desktop";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "Firefox/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "desktop";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "Waterfox/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "desktop";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "Safari/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "desktop";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "Opera/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "desktop";
                }
                else if (req.http.user-agent ~ "curl/")
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = "desktop";
                }
                else
                {
                                set req.http.X-UA = req.http.user-agent;
                }
}
```

Comment: It depenends on what part of the setup is ending SSL negotiation, I've done that with HAProxy sitting in front of varnish (basically, you set the forwarded for header on the SSL endpoint)

Comment: Why not post your config files, rather than having people have to work blind?

Comment: The SSL endpoint is on the apache servers not the varnish cache so unfortunately at the point we could set a header for the SSL endpoint we no longer know what the IP address is.

Comment: Here is the VCL config

Comment: You can get rid of Varnish in your setup if you're passing only HTTPS request to it.

Answer (score 0):

in my default.vcl file I rewrite de "X-Forwarded-For" header this way:

```
sub vcl_recv {

    # your code

    remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

    # your code again
}
```

Don't know if this is the hack you were referring, but this way it's working for us. It's important to remove the actual header, so that it doesn't get transmitted as well as the new one.

We have CloudFlare + Varnish, and everything seems working fine!

Comment: Can you insert headers in an SSL request as we were told this would not work because the packets are encrypted and as the SSL has to pass through varnish encrypted it would not be able to attach a header.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Nginx as a cache you need to add

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
```

in `location`. Similar thing goes for Varnish.

```
sub vcl_rev { 
    set bereq.http.X-Real-IP = client.ip;
    set bereq.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
    set bereq.http.host = req.http.host;
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, I was told that when you receive an SSL request and you are not decrypting that SSL request on varnish itself (being passed through to apache), that the headers are encrypted and as such you cannot add new headers to the connection such as X-Forwarded-For and X-Real-IP. Perhaps my information is wrong, can you confirm?

Comment: If you want to use Nginx just as a SSL wrapper and Varnish as a cache then, Nginx will receive only HTTPS requests and will pass them to Varnish. Indeed Varnish is not able to encrypt/decrypt SSL requests. But I think you can add the headers in Varnish, as in Varnish you receive anyway a normal HTTP request.

Comment: And in the scenario above, Apache will not receive any HTTPS requests. If you want Apache to handle HTTPS requests, what do you need Nginx for? Moreover this way you will not be able to take advantage of Varnish this way. Btw, do you know that Nginx is a full-featured web server and can offer many of the Apache features?

Comment: We essentially use nginx / varnish as a cache / load balancer. Unfortunately we use quite alot of apache specific modules that are not available for nginx. So the idea was to use nginx to handle all the connections as its much better than apache. And then use apache to generate the content that hasn't already been cached.

Comment: In regards to the SSL wrapper we were told varnish could not do this, but I will raise it as a suggestion to see if varnish can add additional headers to an SSL connection without having any access to the contents of the SSL request.

Comment: Also remember that the encrypted traffic goes through nginx, and varnish encrypted and then gets decrypted in apache. So both nginx and varnish only see the encrypted data.

Comment: You could use Nginx as a SSL wrapper and Varnish as the cache. They're both handling well connections. So on a HTTPS request the flow will be browser -> Nginx -> Varnish -> Apache. On a plain HTTP request, the flow will not include Nginx. This way Varnish and Apache will always see the plain content and the encrtypted/decrypted one goes only through Nginx.

Comment: And also you will be able to cache the HTTPS content too. Otherwise, Varnish usage is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify this?

In this scenario you can't even use anything besides a tcp balancer since you can't simply put a plain http cache/proxy like nginx or varnish between as it needs to read (and alter) the http headers which would beat all the ssl/encryption purpose ("man in the middle").

Of course nginx can proxy also https traffic (like proxy_pass https:// yoursite;) to backends but it would still need the SSL certificates for the https to function on client side.

This is why usually the SSL offloading is done on the top level (in your case it would be nginx which then passes the X-Forwarded-For header to varnish which further passes it to apache and apache converts it to client ip).

Comment: unfortunately this requirement is something I have no control over, we have very strict security requirements and I have had to follow them to the letter. What I was wondering is there any other way to pass the IP address that doesn't involve the headers.

For example apache detects the $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] as the address of varnish, could varnish not spoof the IP address so it shows the IP address of the user?

Comment: Well putting varnish between in this case wouldn't make sense anyways (since it would not be able to cache anything / also varnish doesnt understand SSL in any way).

But indeed there is mechanic to "spoof" the client ip - "transparent proxy" or tproxy.
Then again it's not that simple as it involves configuring the whole server (iptables) also as far as I know only Haproxy ( http://haproxy.1wt.eu/ ) and Squid have only real implementation of it.

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution we went with was to route all SSL traffic around varnish, as were not caching it anyway it made more sense to do this. However if anyone does come up with a solution I would be very interested to hear.